# How to read multipart/mixed email from pop3 in.net and com?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, pop3

I have to read emails from pop3. I need some third party application(dll /
Software library) which I can use in C# .net and also for VBA. i.e. I need a third party application which are able to read email from pop3 and also gives support in both .NET or COM.

I have tried for OstroSoft POP3 but  using this I am unable to read plain text body of multipart/mixed email.

Comment: http://www.ostrosoft.com/ospop3.aspx is the refrence for  OstroSoft POP3

Answer (score 0):

The multipart/mime bits of an email body end up as attachments.